# Understanding a Go race condition example from the official blog

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm reading through https://blog.golang.org/race-detector and I'm not fully convinced of why Example 1 is a race condition. The following is an excerpt of the code with a race condition (lines 14-16):

```
11 func main() {
12     start := time.Now()
13     var t *time.Timer
14     t = time.AfterFunc(randomDuration(), func() {
15         fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start))
16         t.Reset(randomDuration())
17     })
18     time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
19 }
20 
21 func randomDuration() time.Duration {
22     return time.Duration(rand.Int63n(1e9))
23 }
```

The blog post goes on to give this explanation for why there is a race condition:

> If the initial timer duration is very small, the timer function may fire before the main goroutine has assigned a value to t and so the call to t.Reset is made with a nil t.

I'm not following why the duration matters for the return value. Even if `time.AfterFunc` is running in a separate goroutine, wouldn't it provide a return value before going on to execute its code? What changes given a sufficiently long duration where the return value is populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given example, the following execution is possible:

1. call time.AfterFunc()
2. time.AfterFunc() starts a goroutine that waits for the timer to strike. time.Afterfunc continues running.
3. timer strikes, calls the afterfunc
4. afterFunc call t.Reset -> panic, because t will be set at step 5
5. call to time.AfterFunc() returns, sets t

Comment: Isn't step 2: `time.AfterFunc` attaches the goroutine to the timer's expiry?

Comment: @John, yes, but that timer is created in `AfterFunc`, which has not returned yet, so `t` is not set.

Comment: Thank you, this and looking at the source code (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/sleep.go#L167-L176) helped it make sense. Between line 175 and 176 it might call `t.Reset` but the `t` pointer has not been initialized with the return value yet.

Comment: My point was that step 2 doesn't involve waiting, @BurakSerdar.

Comment: @John, changed the wording a bit